# Elastic query with wildcard and fuzziness on multiple fields

Tags: elasticsearch

**TL;DR:** How do I construct an Elastic query with one serach term on multiple fields that supports both fuzziness and wildcards?

I am trying to construct an Elastic query where all search prompts (the string inside the query-field) contain the exact same value.

The query should match on two fields:

1. addressRange
2. documentnumber

The query below that I have constructed does support fuzziness, which is great, but it does not support wildcards.

So for example; if the addressRange-value is "*Happy Frogsroad 42*" I would not only like "*H**o**ppy Frogsroad 42*" to result in a match (which is now possible with the fuzziness), but I would also like to get a result when I search for "*ogsroa*".

How could I make this work?

```
# Fuzziness works, searching on substrings (of keywords) does not
GET /document/_search 
{
  "query": 
  {
    "bool": 
    {
      "should": 
      [
        {
          "match": 
          {
            "adresRange": 
            {
              "_name": "adresRange",
              "operator": "or",
              "query": "aod",
              "fuzziness": 1
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "match": 
          {
            "documentNumber": 
            {
              "_name": "documentNumber",
              "operator": "or",
              "query": "aod",
              "fuzziness": 0
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can combine the wildcard query to get results with "".
however be aware of the performance of the [wildcard query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-wildcard-query.html).

> Avoid beginning patterns with * or ?. This can increase the iterations
> needed to find matching terms and slow search performance.

Another option is to use [n-gram](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-ngram-tokenizer.html) or [edge-gram](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-edgengram-tokenizer.html) to search for substrings, in general I think this option is better.

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "minimum_should_match": 1,
      "should": [
        {
          "wildcard": {
            "adresRange.keyword": {
              "value": "*ogsroa*"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "adresRange": {
              "query": "ogsroa",
              "fuzziness": 2
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "documentNumber": {
              "query": "ogsroa",
              "fuzziness": 1
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: That worked like a charm, thanks! So far no noticable performance issues while using the wildcard, but I will keep an eye on it!